# How to prioritize OpenVPN over local network?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, connection

I am running on Ubuntu 18.04 and have openVPN.
My remote AWS instance has the same network as my home's one.

How can I force / prioritize VPN over LAN?

I want my PC to firstly connect to the instances over VPN if my VPN is open.

Please advise if it's possible.

Comment: Having the same network on both sides is doable, but not advisable. Can you post the output of `# ifconfig` when the VPN is up? To better understand the layout.

Comment: But it doesn't look like you are using the same network ... Anyway, you need to add a route to the ip destination via the VPN. You add the route when the VPN is up (something like `ip route add destination dev VPN_DEVICE`) and then, with you turn off the VPN, you remove the route. [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/767261/how-to-automatically-add-a-local-route-after-openvpn-start) explains how to add a route when OpenVPN starts.